# How is the Opera Search History icon activated?

Tags: opera

How can the Opera Search History icon be activated?

As far as I know it is not there right after installation.
But it is in my current installation...

**Update 1**: it turned out to be a bookmark to 
"opera:historysearch" that  I inadvertently had placed in the 
tab bar.

---

Details:

The Search History feature (search engine for locally stored
web pages retrieved by Opera) can be activated by typing
"opera:historysearch" in the address bar. There can also be
an icon ("five star") for Search History in the same line as the open
pages bar that when clicked on will do the same thing.

However after installation it is supposed to look like:

[image]

In my current installation it looks like this:

[image]

How can it be activated in a fresh installation?

Platform: Opera v9.64, Windows XP SP2 64 bit, 8 GB RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an actual icon specifically for the history search. It's a bookmark you've put there at one point.

Do as you would to bring it up in a tab:

> opera:historysearch

Then click and drag the icon next to the location, in this case it looks like a page with a dog-eared corner, and position it to the left of the New Tab icon (plus sign in a circle) to where you see a highlighted bar glow.

[image: Opera history search]

Release and you will now see the star icon next to the New Tab icon.

Next time you want to bring up the History Search, you can just click that star.

If you want to remove it later on, right-click the icon and select "Remove From Toolbar"

Comment: +1. Thanks for solving this mystery and for a very good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably once you have some history to search ?

Comment: Yes, but I have report from somebody else that the star icon is absent.

Comment: Sorry thought you were asking why was it disabled on a new install

Answer (score 1):

You can just do the search in the address bar by starting with the letter h. At least I find that a lot more convenient. Never really use the other search bars at all :p So for instance:

> h super user history search

Comment: The two kinds of searches are not identical - or least the display. "opera:historysearch" gives a Google-like result web page whereas "h" gives a table-like result. But thanks for a very useful tip.